# Are brittle unit tests always a bad thing?

Tags: unit-testing

At times I find a very [brittle test](http://www.thedeveloperday.com/avoiding-brittle-tests-testing-output/) to be a good thing because when I change the intent of the code under test I want to make sure my unit test breaks so that I'm forced to refactor ... is this approach not recommended when building a large suite of regression tests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general statement admonishing brittle unit tests applies mostly to shops which haven't fully embraced unit testing. For instance, when trying to convert from having no tests to having a full suite of unit tests, or when your project is the unit testing pilot project. In these cases developers get used to false positives from unit tests and begin to ignore them. Then the unit tests fall behind the production code and either get left behind or require a major effort to update.

I would say you should always aim for the least brittle tests you can that fully test your function/module, but if you have 1 or 2 that are brittle you should be okay in most cases.

Answer (score 12):

Unit tests **must** be brittle -- it **must** be easy to break them.  If they don't break, then they're not unit tests at all; they're code comments.

...

or am I missing the point of the question?

---

**Edit:** I should clarify my earlier answer.

I was being a bit pedantic about the language.  "brittle" just means "easy to break".  A unit test *should* be easy to break.  The term "brittle tests" should really be "*overly*-brittle tests"; tests that break when they shouldn't.  Even so, it's much, much easier to fix an over-brittle test than to fix a bug that slipped through an under-brittle test, so go ahead and write your brittle tests!

Comment: I disagree, fixing brittle tests means a lot of maintain. One of the purposes of unit testing is to reduce maintain. UnitTest must have only one logical reason to fail.

Comment: @Restuta The purpose of unit tests is to enforce that they behaviour or methods stays consistent. Enforcing consistence guards against bugs. Catching these bugs early leads to less maintenance. Do not confuse purpose with effect.

Comment: @Restuta I think by brittle the author meant that the unit tests break for the wrong reasons. The tests should only break if your tested method misbehaves, if the tests easily break because of other changes / dependencies then they are "brittle".

Comment: @Artem Goutsoul agree, that is my understanding.

Comment: No, a unit test should be sensitive to contract violations. If it is sensitive to anything else, it is brittle – that's my definition. A good unit test does not *break*, it *fails*. A broken one needs fixing, a failing one shows you a bug. A failing unit test is one that alerts you to a burglar, a broken unit test stubs its toe and breaks its nose. You have to take it to the hospital, but you still don't know if it was just being stupid, or whether there is a burglar. Also, there is a lot of confusion over testing narrow contracts (spoiler: you stick to the domain because UB is untestable).

Answer (score 6):

IMO, as long as your tests make sure that your app code does what it should do, and if changed, the tests fail, then your tests are fine. Could you define what exactly you mean by "brittle"?

Just make sure that your tests really cover every aspect of your app code. (Within reason).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, brittleness of tests is always a bad thing. But it seems to be one of those things that we have to live with in order to fully test our classes. Many classes can't be tested like black boxes that take some input and return some output, like you might see with Math.cos(). Most of them have side effects on other classes or entities in the system and you have to test that those entities were manipulated properly by the class. That means the test has to know implementation details about the class being tested, which creates brittle classes.

Brittle tests are like proctology exams. They are definitely bad, unpleasant things, but we must put up with them because we have no better choice.

Answer (score 4):

As dysfunctor points out, unit tests should be brittle in that they are easy to break. However, I would add that they should not be brittle in that they pass or fail randomly.

This happens a lot in tests that involve threads and sockets. Tests should make use of mutexes and other "wait" devices to avoid the tests failing under uncontrollable circumstances, such as high processor load.

A definite "smell" of a randomly-brittle test is the use of a sleep() function in a test.

Comment: I would argue that your tests should be simulating the socket or thread work through the use of mocks. Testing actual socket communication is an integration test. A Unit Test should test that the implementation worked as expected with the assumption that the socket communication worked.

You say that use of "sleep" is a sign of smell but before that you say to use other "wait" devices, so which is it? I think any use of "wait" devices is the sign that this test should really be an integration test and the behavior should be split out to a unit test with mocks. My 2c.

Comment: By wait devices, I mean any non-polling mechanism - callbacks, or a wait mutex, ideally. Or select() ;) I agree in general that mocks should definitely be used whereever possible.

Comment: Oof, cut me deep with that remark about sleep! Just slip a cheeky little sleep in here and it should pass most of the time unless the system is very busy- good enough, ship it!

Answer (score 3):

When a code change meant to be "internal" to a class (i.e. not changing the API), causes a test to fail, there are two possibilities:

1. The code has a new bug, OR
2. The code is correct, the test needs fixing

Try to reduce #2. Those are the 'brittle' tests.

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests are by definition brittle. They break when related code (the system under test) changes. That's by design. That's how unit tests provide value.

What we want to avoid is tests which break when the code changes but the logic does not. For example, having the majority of existing tests break when adding a new requirement is undesirable.

Unfortunately, avoiding such brittleness is not easy. In all but the simplest of cases, the unit test will have some knowledge about the implementation of the system under test (eg. mocked objects). As long as that is true, test will be brittle.

The best way to avoid that problem is to avoid writing classes that need to change. This is actually easier than it sounds when adhering to SOLID principles.